# symfony 3 UndefinedOptionsException - Dropdown from Database

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I have two entities **Student** and **Classes** and I want to create a form shows the student details and a dropdown / chocelist of classes and assign one class to the student. Also the classes should come from the DB table so the controller is like this.

```
public function studentAddClassAction( $id, Request $request )
{
    // get the student from the student table
    $em     = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $student= $em->getRepository('PIE10Bundle:Student')->find($id);

    // new class object and create the form
    $class  = new Classes;
    $form   = $this->createForm(ClassesType::class, $class);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if( $form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid() )
    {
        // form operation - update student row with the classID
    }

    return $this->render(
                        'PIE10Bundle:student:layout_student_addclass.html.twig',
                        array(
                            'student'=> $student,
                            'title'  => 'Add Class',
                            'tables' => 1,
                            'form'   => $form->createView()
                        )
    );
}
```

and my **ClassesType** is like below

```
class ClassesType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('classes',
                      ClassesType::class,
                      array(
                            'class'     => 'PIE10Bundle:Classes',
                            'property'  => 'className',
                            'expanded'  => false,
                            'multiple'  => false
                    ));
        $builder->add('Add Class',
                      SubmitType::class,
                      array('attr'  =>  array('class' => 'btn btn-primary',
                                              'style' => 'margin:15px 0;')) );
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'PIE10Bundle\Entity\Classes',

        ));
    }
}
```

and when I try to access this form I am getting the following **500 Internal Server Error - UndefinedOptionsException** error

> The options "class", "expanded", "multiple", "property" do not exist. Defined options are: "action", "allow_extra_fields", "attr", "auto_initialize", "block_name", "by_reference", "compound", "constraints", "csrf_field_name", "csrf_message", "csrf_protection", "csrf_token_id", "csrf_token_manager", "data", "data_class", "description", "disabled", "empty_data", "error_bubbling", "error_mapping", "extra_fields_message", "inherit_data", "invalid_message", "invalid_message_parameters", "label", "label_attr", "label_format", "mapped", "method", "post_max_size_message", "property_path", "required", "translation_domain", "trim", "validation_groups".

So I need to know what went wrong and how to fix this. Please let me know if any other information needed. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `ClassesType` change:

```
$builder->add('classes', ClassesType::class, ...
```

to:

```
$builder->add('classes', EntityType::class, ...
```

also add:

```
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
```

at the top of your file, for it to be available.

---

Currently you're using `ClassesType` itself (which would problably result in an infinite loop if it weren't for the errors). This type does not extend the `EntityType` and thus the options you're using (`class`, `expanded`, `multiple`, `property`) do not exist.

Also not that `property` is deprecated, you should use `choice_label/choice_value` unless you're using a rather old version of symfony.

---

Reference: [EntityType Field](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html)

Comment: Thanks for this and I have tried it and it gives `Could not load type "PIE10Bundle\Form\EntityType"`

Comment: I have added the namespace but with no luck now geting `The option "property" does not exist. Defined options are: "action", "allow_extra_fields", "attr",`.... etc

Comment: Please update your question with the new code, also add which symfony version you're using (check composer.json if you don't know).

Comment: I could solve it with use of your `$builder->add('classes', EntityType::class, ...` plus the namespace and the following answer. I am using 3.1.3 version BTW Thanks. :))

Answer (score 0):

With use of @Yoshi answer I changed the

`$builder->add('classes', ClassesType::class, ...`

to

`$builder->add('classes', EntityType::class, ...`

and also added the

`use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;` to the **ClassesType** file and then updated the **Controller** like below

```
public function studentAddClassAction( $id, Request $request )
{
    // get the student from the student table
    $em     = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $student= $em->getRepository('PIE10Bundle:Student')->find($id);

    // new class object and create the form
    $class  = $em->getRepository('PIE10Bundle:Classes')->findAll();
    $form   = $this->createForm(ClassesType::class, $class);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if( $form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid() )
    {
        // form operation - update student row with the classID
    }

    return $this->render(
                        'PIE10Bundle:student:layout_student_addclass.html.twig',
                        array(
                            'student'=> $student,
                            'title'  => 'Add Class',
                            'tables' => 1,
                            'form'   => $form->createView()
                        )
    );
}
```

and then the **ClassesType** as follow

```
class ClassesType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('classes',
                      EntityType::class,
                      array(
                            'class'     => 'PIE10Bundle:Classes',
                            'expanded'  => false,
                            'multiple'  => false
                    ));
        $builder->add('Add Class',
                      SubmitType::class,
                      array('attr'  =>  array('class' => 'btn btn-primary',
                                              'style' => 'margin:15px 0;')) );
    }
}
```

@Yoshi answer helped me to fix the error